# Error converting datatype nvarchar to int in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I do the following:

```
DECLARE @return_code_as_nvarchar AS NVARCHAR(16)
SET @return_code_as_nvarchar = CAST(@return_code AS NVARCHAR)

DECLARE @notification_message AS NVARCHAR(255)
SET @notification_message = N'New Activity added with Id ' + @return_code_as_nvarchar

EXEC dbo.AddNote 0, @responsible_username, @notification_message
```

But I get the error in the title. Where am I going wrong with this casting? The error message sounds backwards too as I am trying to convert an integer to an nvarchar not an nvarchar to an integer.

Comment: On what row do you get this error?

Comment: No particular row. It's from a procedure where I insert a new notification in the database.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are going to need to post the definition of `dbo.AddNote`. As an aside, you should **always** [specify a length when declaring varchar/nvarchar, or casting/converting to varchar/nvarchar.](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) `CAST(@return_code AS NVARCHAR)` should be `CAST(@return_code AS NVARCHAR(16))`

Comment: I figured it out. I forgot to remove the first parameter from an earlier iteration of the procedure, so it tried to put an nvarchar where an int should go.